# inserting an array in a fpdf data for graph

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I have to put an array inside a graph data
this is the original format

```
$data = array( "DATA_1title" => DATA1, "DATA_2title" => DATA2);
```

this is statement with php

```
    $sqlb = "SELECT date_format(datesales, '%M %D %Y') as datesales,
    sum(amount) as amount from sales
    where date(datesales) <= curdate() and
    date(datesales) >= curdate() - interval 6 day
    group by DATE_FORMAT(datesales, '%M %D %Y')";
    $resultb = $conn->query($sqlb);
    while($rowb = $resultb->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $datesales = $rowb['datesales'];
        $amount = $rowb['amount'];
    }
```

I tried this code

```
    $sqlb = "SELECT date_format(datesales, '%M %D %Y') as datesales,
    sum(amount) as amount from sales
    where date(datesales) <= curdate() and
    date(datesales) >= curdate() - interval 6 day
    group by DATE_FORMAT(datesales, '%M %D %Y')";
    $resultb = $conn->query($sqlb);
    while($rowb = $resultb->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $datesales=$rowb['datesales'];
        $amount=$rowb['amount'];

        $data = array( "$datesales" => $amount,);
    }
```

but it only displays one value
and not an array of values
I also tried this

```
$sqlb = "SELECT date_format(datesales, '%M %D %Y') as datesales,
    sum(amount) as amount from sales
    where date(datesales) <= curdate() and
    date(datesales) >= curdate() - interval 6 day
    group by DATE_FORMAT(datesales, '%M %D %Y')";
    $resultb = $conn->query($sqlb);
    while($rowb = $resultb->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $data = array( "$rowb['datesales']" => $rowb['amount'],);
    }
```

but I got the same result
what I want is that instead of manually typing the key and value every time, it can instead be pulled out of the database with the sql statement I did.

```
Instead of this 
$data = array( "DATA_1title" => DATA1, "DATA_2title" => DATA2);
```

```
I want it to be like this
**SQL STATEMENT HERE**
$data = array( "$datetimes" => $amount);

$datetimes refers to the alias in the sql statement which is an array
so is $amount
```

Comment: Could you explain the output? Would you want `datesales` to be the key and `amount` to be the value? This would be so much easier if you used PDO instead of mysqli.

Comment: I'm using fpdf to create a pdf graph, the **ORIGINAL CODE** is an array to input values for the graph. so the result I'm expecting is instead of manually typing the key and value I want the key and value to be pulled out of the database(````datesales```` and ````amount```` in the sql statement)

Comment: instead of this ````$data = array( "DATA_1title" => DATA1, "DATA_2title" => DATA2);````

Comment: I want it to somehow get their respective data from the sql statement above 
````$sqlb = "SELECT date_format(datesales, '%M %D %Y') as datesales,
    sum(amount) as amount from sales
    where date(datesales) <= curdate() and
    date(datesales) >= curdate() - interval 6 day
    group by DATE_FORMAT(datesales, '%M %D %Y')";
    $resultb = $conn->query($sqlb);
    while($rowb = $resultb->fetch_assoc())
    {   }
````

Comment: Could you just edit the question and write by hand a sample output that you expect, please?

Comment: done, you can take a look at the edited question

Comment: I don't see any sample output. All you put in the edit is `$data = array( "$datetimes" => $amount);` which makes zero sense. What should the `$data` array contain?

Comment: I edited it again, please have a look

Comment: I still don't know what you want, but maybe `foreach($resultb as $rowb){ $data[$rowb['datesales']] = $rowb['amount']; }` instead of the whole `while` loop?

Comment: I'm sorry for poor explanation. That is exactly what I want. Can you post that answer so I can mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use one value as a key and the other as a value. For example:

```
// instead of your while loop
foreach($resultb as $rowb) {
    $data[$rowb['datesales']] = $rowb['amount'];
}
```